# Pgp key in terraform for aws_iam_user_login_profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I am new to terraform creating iam user using terraform

below is the .tf file

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "lb" {
  name = "Ec2_view"

  # path = "/system/"
  # tags = {
  #   tag-key = "tag-value"
  # }
}

resource "aws_iam_access_key" "lb" {
  user = "${aws_iam_user.lb.name}"
}

resource "aws_iam_user_policy" "lb_ro" {
  name = "test"
  user = "${aws_iam_user.lb.name}"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "ec2:Describe*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_user_login_profile" "u" {
  user                    = "${aws_iam_user.lb.name}"
  password_reset_required = true
  pgp_key="keybase:terraform_user"
}

output "password" {
value="${aws_iam_user_login_profile.u.encrypted_password"
}
```

what does pgp_key mean in aws_iam_user_login_profile and steps to create pgp_key and using it in terraform code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Got the answer

1. Need to install Keybase in our local
2. need to create Keybase key by using `keybase pgp gen`
3. then give the reference of this Keybase key in your terraform code `keybase:username_of_keybase`
4. Then terraform apply
5. Then we need to get the decrypted password

```sh
terraform output -raw password | base64 --decode | keybase pgp decrypt
```

Comment: Is this still best practice in 2021? The terraform documentation [LINK](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_user_login_profile) is vague but still recommends keybase. then when I installed/ran "keybase pgp gen" it asked my for 2+ email addresses, which seemed strange...

Comment: Just enter to skip for additional email requests @CullenD

Answer (score 4):

An alternative answer that avoids using Keybase entirely, **is by generating your own PGP keys for encryption**. This is convenient if your organization does not use Keybase and / or you don't want to create a Keybase account.

There is a wonderful blog post [here](https://menendezjaume.com/post/gpg-encrypt-terraform-secrets/) that breaks down most of the steps, but to simplify:

1. Create your PGP key locally:

   ```bash
   # confirm you have pgp installed, check for existing keys
   gpg -k

   # create a new key
   # IMPORTANT: with your real name, email, and optionally a passphrase
   gpg --gen-key

   # export your key for the email used
   gpg --output public-key-binary.gpg --export <YOUR_EMAIL>@<X.DOMAIN.com>
   ```
2. Setup a reference for your AWS IAM resource `aws_iam_access_key` per the Terraform documentation [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_access_key#pgp_key)

   ```
   data "local_file" "pgp_key" {
     filename = abspath("./relative/path/to/your/public-key-binary.gpg")
   }

   resource "aws_iam_access_key" "lb" {
     user = aws_iam_user.lb.name
     pgp_key = data.local_file.pgp_key.content_base64
   }

   output "password" {
     value = aws_iam_access_key.lb.encrypted_secret
   }
   ```
3. Proceed to `terraform init`, `validate`, `plan`, and `apply` when you are ready to deploy for IaC
4. Post deployment of your IAM user, you can decrypt the sensitive secret_key using the following command:

   ```bash
   terraform output password | base64 --decode | gpg --decrypt --pinentry-mode=loopback
   ```

   > Skip the `--pinentry-mode=loopback` flag if you did *not* set a passphrase on PGP key generation

Comment: You made my day :heart: